# Как выделить суффикс слова с помощью python?

Tags: python, nlp

Задача стоит в том, чтобы определить уменьшительно-ласкательные слова в тексте. Я предположил, что с помощью нахождения ум-ласк суффиксов можно найти такие слова. Варианты, которые не работают:

1. просто найти эти суффиксы в слове. Почему не работает: есть суффикс "очк", есть слово "точка". Если просто искать этот суффикс в этом слове, то мы выделим часть корня.
2. pymorphy2 - может сделать только первоначальную форму, либо менять падежи, сделать морфологический разбор слова
3. стемминг - убирает только окончания

Примеры ввода и вывода программы:

```
отверточка - очк
счетик - ик
хорошенький - еньк
ласточка - (ничего)
точка - (ничего)
```

Comment: Готовых решений сходу не нашел. Можно на коленке что-то набросать, что-то типа того: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157867/4752653 , в том числе поставить ограничение, что корень не может состоять из одной буквы

Comment: Примеры искомых слов и суффиксов приведите в вопросе, пожалуйста. Вот "морфологический разбор" - это не оно случайно? )

Comment: @CrazyElf морфологический - это определение части речи, по составу слова - это морфемный разбор. pymorphy2 по составу не умеет разбирать.

Comment: @insolor Но в нём есть `KnownSuffixAnalyzer`, он не мог бы помочь?

Comment: пробовал это, корень он не выделяет, работает также как и в первом случае у меня в вопросе. Ограничение на одну букву в корне нельзя поставить, и нельзя точно определить, минимальную длину корня. Есть еще слово "ласточка" и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf вряд ли, насколько я знаю, он только пытается по суффиксу определить часть речи (причем кажется под суффиксом и окончание тоже подразумевается)

Comment: @Makss123 этимологически "очк" в ласточке это и есть уменьшительный суффикс. Вообще, все зависит от того, насколько общую задачу вам нужно решить. Если полностью обобщенно для русского языка, то нужен корпус текстов с разборами, на основе которого строите модель. Если у вас какая-то более ограниченная задача, то делаете на коленке с набором известных приставок, суффиксов, окончаний, плюс какие-то исключения (известные корни?), типа той же ласточки.

Comment: И всё же добавьте в вопрос некую табличку с примерами - вот здесь есть уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс, а здесь нет. Чем больше примеров, тем лучше. А там уже можно посмотреть, что с этим можно сделать, как разные библиотеки на эти примеры реагируют, есть ли в их выдаче полезная инфа.

Comment: Добавил примеры ввода и вывода

Comment: изменил немного условие, изначально мне нужно было найти уменьшительно-ласкательные слова